# Restrict XML type from other namespace

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to inherit from a type defined in a base XML file but i want to make one modification. The element that is optional in schema of base file must be mandatory in my new schema file. The namespaces are different and i can't change them. What is the better solution for this? I have the code below but presents errors.

file base.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
targetNamespace="http://basetype"
xmlns="http://basetype">

<xs:element name="BaseTypeElement" type="BaseType"/>

<xs:complexType name="BaseType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

file restrictbasetype.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
targetNamespace="http://restrictbasetype"
xmlns:bas="http://basetype"
xmlns="http://restrictbasetype">

<xs:import schemaLocation="base.xsd" namespace="http://basetype"/> 

<xs:element name="RestrictedElement" type="BaseTypeRestriction"/>

<xs:complexType name="BaseTypeRestriction">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="bas:BaseType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
                <!-- name is now mandatory -->
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the collision between namespaces.

Your first schema `base.xsd` has `{http://basetype}` target namespace.
And your second schema `restrictbasetype.xsd` has `{restrictbasetype.xsd}` target namespace. Additionally, both your schema specify `elementFormDefault="qualified"` attribute in their heads, which means that all locally declared elements are qualified, that is belong to the target namespaces of their schemas. For an XML processor, all that means that both your schemas defines complete different things. So, they may just coexist but cannot enforce anything to each other.

Specifically, here is what is wrong:

```
<xs:complexType name="BaseTypeRestriction">
  <xs:complexContent>
     <!-- The restriction means that anything defined inside it may be just
      overridings fully compatible with the content defined by parent type: 'bas:BaseType'
     -->
     <xs:restriction base="bas:BaseType">
       <xs:sequence>
         <!-- But here you actually declare an element with the qualified name:
          {http://restrictbasetype}:id. It won't override the 'id' element in
          'bas:BaseType' because that one has the qulified name: {http://basetype}:id. 
          On the other hand, you cannot even extend the content of 'bas:BaseType' 
          because it is the restriction.
          So, this particular declaration is completely wrong!
         -->
         <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>

         <!-- the same is for this -->
         <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
       </xs:sequence>
     </xs:restriction>
   </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>
```

So, what can you do to make your intention work? You should **remove** `elementFormDefault="qualified"` in both your schema heads. Then, any locally declared elements will be in the same `{no namespace}` and, therefore, possible to override.

These schemas did work by me:

base.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- no 'elementFormDefault' attribute -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://basetype"
           xmlns="http://basetype">

  <xs:element name="BaseTypeElement" type="BaseType"/>

  <xs:complexType name="BaseType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

restrictbasetype.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- no 'elementFormDefault' attribute -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://restrictbasetype"
           xmlns:bas="http://basetype"
           xmlns="http://restrictbasetype">

  <xs:import schemaLocation="base.xsd" namespace="http://basetype"/> 

  <xs:element name="RestrictedElement" type="BaseTypeRestriction"/>

  <xs:complexType name="BaseTypeRestriction">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:restriction base="bas:BaseType">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:long"/>
            <!-- name is now mandatory -->
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

---

Promo add-on. These links may be interesting for those working with XML schemas and WSDL: [FlexDoc/XML](http://www.flexdoc.xyz/flexdoc-xml/) [XSDDoc](http://www.flexdoc.xyz/flexdoc-xml/xsddoc/) & [WSDLDoc](http://www.flexdoc.xyz/flexdoc-xml/wsdldoc/) – High-performance universal XML Schema / WSDL Documentation Generators with Diagrams